# How to correctly configure IoTEdge Module to report data to Remote Monitoring

Tags: azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-suite

As the title says, whats the correct way to configure an IoTEdge Module to report data to Remote Monitoring?
Actually I have a custom module running on an IoTEdge device that is working correctly (I can check that is working properly by looking at the docker logs of the module) , but its not transmitting anything to the Remote monitoring dashboard, by the way the device is listed on the available devices on the Azure Remote Monitoring but it is offline. I suppose that it depends on the MessageSchema and MessageTemplate that are not configured. I can't find any specific documentation about this topic, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to get the message schema right. Articles like these might help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-suite/iot-suite-remote-monitoring-device-schema
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-suite/iot-suite-connecting-devices-linux
I don't know much about Remote Monitoring, but I wonder if it will have problems with the module concept since it's designed for devices.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about the original V1 version of the remote monitoring solution, or the newer V2 version?  If it's the original version, you would need to, at least once, send a DeviceInfo structure (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-suite/iot-suite-v1-remote-monitoring-device-info#device-metadata) to the IoTHub associated with the solution.  I haven't tried it yet, but it should work for the edge device (I don't *think* it would have an issue with the module concept).  If it's the V2 version, I would need to investigate further.